# Name of fast card game with penalties?

Tags: identify-this-game

- Goal: First player to run out of cards wins.
- Deal: Divide cards evenly and place face down in a deck in front of each player.
- Play is fast.
- Penalties:

  - If a player takes too long, opponents can yell ***penalty*** and every player gives them a card.
  - If a player makes a mistake, opponents can yell ***penalty*** and every player gives them a card.

Rules:

1. The top face up card of the player's discard pile must be played if possible before player touches top card of player's deck; if not, ***penalty.***
2. Aces and kings can be placed each in their own stack in the centre.
3. Twos must be placed on an ace of the same suit and threes on twos of the same suit etc. if the cards are in an ace stack otherwise ***penalty.***
4. Red queens must be placed on a black king and black queens on red kings, jacks must be be placed on the opposite colour queens and so on and so on, if the cards are in a king stack otherwise ***penalty.***
5. Cards must be transferred from king stacks to ace stacks if possible otherwise ***penalty.***
6. The player keeps playing cards as long as they can place cards otherwise ***penalty.***
7. If the top face up card of the discard pile can not be played then:
8. if the deck is empty the player turns over the discard pile and it becomes their new deck;
9. if there is no deck or discard pile, they have won.
10. The top face down card is turned over if it can be placed and their turn continues; goto step 1 otherwise.
11. The unplaced card is placed face up on the discard pile and their turn is over.
12. The player watches like a hawk as the other players take their turn ready to yell ***penalty.***
13. Play continues around the circle.

I used to play this years ago.

I searched for it under "penalty" but I get games that are not this.